# Error Cleaning Up Jobs in Kubernetes 1.21

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

This started happening when we upgraded to Kubernetes 1.21.  The following message occurs:

```
Jul 08 07:00:01        1 cronjob_controllerv2.go:193] "error cleaning up jobs" cronjob="default/vet-messenger-batch-prod-hourly" resourceVersion="160274892" err="Operation cannot be fulfilled on cronjobs.batch \"vet-messenger-batch-prod-hourly\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"
Jul 08 07:00:01        1 cronjob_controllerv2.go:154] error syncing CronJobController default/vet-messenger-batch-prod-hourly, requeuing: Operation cannot be fulfilled on cronjobs.batch "vet-messenger-batch-prod-hourly": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

The Cronjob is pretty simple:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: vet-messenger-batch-prod-hourly
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: vet-messenger-batch-prod
              image: REDACTED/vet-messenger:prod
              command: ["yarn", "batch:start:prod"]
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              env:
                - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: k8s-container-runner-prod
                      key: aws_access_key_id
                - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: k8s-container-runner-prod
                      key: aws_secret_access_key
                - name: AWS_REGION
                  value: us-east-1
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 1
```

We tried deleting and recreating the cronjob both with `kubectl create -f` and `kubectl apply -f` and neither seems to work.  Note the API version was at `batch/v1beta1` before we upgraded, and we did change it to `batch/v1` to squelch the deprecation notice.

Also, weirdly, the job harvester seems to be working flawlessly anyway.  It keeps the last three run jobs and deletes the older ones, as it has always done (and is the default).

Comment: Delete the CronJob and make sure all the previous Jobs and Pods of this CronJob has been removed. If not removed, remove them manually. Then, recreate the CronJob again.

Comment: @EmruzHossain Did that already.  Removing the CronJob does successfully remove all linked jobs ...

Comment: @CraigRiecke did the above solve your issue?

Comment: @PawełGrondal Unfortunately no.

Comment: This may be a problem with new CronJob controller. If possible, try passing `--feature-gates="CronJobControllerV2=false"` flag to kube-controller-manager.

Comment: Mmmm, I would try that if (1) I knew how to do it (2) something was actually not working.  The Cronjob works.  Jobs spwaned from it get cleaned up.  It's just the error that's confusing, so we don't want to throw out the baby with the bath water.

Comment: @CraigRiecke i am facing exactly the same issue. any fix for it ?